# concatenating date and time column in SQL server 2000 with different data type

Tags: sql-server, date, time, concatenation, field

I have a table with the date and time column as below

```
       Date           |      Time
```

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000   |    05.26.13

2013-09-16 00:00:00.000   |    10.36.09

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000   |    11.58.35

Datatype for Date field is datetime and the Datatype for time field is varchar. I want to concatenate these two field and get the output like below in a new field

2013-08-23 05:26:13.000

2013-09-16 10:36:09.000

2013-10-21 11:58:36.000

The basic requirement is that the above time is in PST time zone and I want to convert it into EST, MST, AST and CST time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the full date and time in PST can be done by taking the relevant string parts and adding them to the date:

```
select 
  dateadd(hour, cast(left(theTime,2) as int), 
  dateadd(minute, cast(substring(theTime, 4,2) as int), 
  dateadd(second, cast(right(theTime, 2) as int), theDate))) as dateTimePST
```

Converting the *dateTimePST* to any other timezone taking Daylight saving time (DST) into account is not possible in SQL-Server 2000 using a built-in function. Depending on your specific situation, you could add some conversion tables to your database, or do the conversion in your business logic, or some other solution suitable to your situation.